# i18n HTML escaping not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

According to Ruby on Rails Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations) all I need to do to render my translations without calling `html_safe` on them is to have the key name end with `_html`. This is what I tried:

```
en:
  breadcrumbs:
    root_html: "<i class='material-icons'>home</i>"
```

Calling it like this:

```
I18n.t('breadcrumbs.root_html')
```

causes the output to be this very string defined inside my translations, but not the rendered HTML.
What am I doing wrong?

Using Ruby on Rails 4.2.1.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try `I18n.t('breadcrumbs.root.html')` (also, may along with changing `root_html:` to `root:`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scrolling down a little further in the guide I found the problem:

> Automatic conversion to HTML safe translate text is only available from the translate view helper method.

Since I tried to prepare the link inside my controller and pass it through a gem to the view, this didn't work.

To make this work you'll have to call `html_safe` on the string, like so:

```
I18n.t('breadcrumbs.root_html').html_safe
```

If you find another solution, hit me up!

Comment: Same here. I didn't know there's a difference between I18n.t(:my_html) and view helper t(:my_html) either, thx for this hint!

Comment: <h1><%= I18n.t(:yourkey).html_safe %></h1> it works for me